# Adding double quotes to string is giving me incorrect data in Python

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to add double quotes to each line in the file , in the file output (I want .tsv output file) I am getting four double quotes around the string, it gives me proper result when I am writing it to .csv file format. Code is as follows

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/Users/name/Documents/TA/sample.tsv',delimiter='\t',encoding='utf-8')

re_vin = re.compile(r'^.*\s')

vin_quotes = []

with open('C:/Users/name/Documents/TA/sample.tsv') as f:

    for line in f:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        line_quotes = '"{}"'.format(line)
        vin_quotes.append(line_quotes)


vin_df = pd.DataFrame(data = vin_quotes[1:])

vin_df.to_csv('C:/Users/name/Documents/TA/processed.tsv', sep='\t', encoding='utf-8',index= False)
```

Sample data is as follows

```
**cvdt35    Output from code**
1GADP5B """1GADP5B"""
1GADP5G """1GADP5G"""
1GAHP2G """1GAHP2G"""
1GM5K8D """1GM5K8D"""
1GM5K8H """1GM5K8H"""
1GMCU0G """1GMCU0G"""
1GMCU9G """1GMCU9G"""
1GMJK1J """1GMJK1J"""
1GTEW1E """1GTEW1E"""
2GMPK4A """2GMPK4A"""
3GA6P0H """3GA6P0H"""
3GA6P0L """3GA6P0L"""
3GA6P0L """3GA6P0L"""
3GAHP0H """3GAHP0H"""
```

expected output

```
"1GADP5B","1GADP5G","1GAHP2G","1GM5K8D","1GM5K8H","1GMCU0G","1GMCU9G","1GMJK1J","1GTEW1E","2GMPK4A","3GA6P0H","3GA6P0L","3GA6P0L","3GAHP0H"
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you just use [`re.findall(r'[^\s"]+', str)`](https://regex101.com/r/SVWD1R/1), wrap in `"`, then join on `,`?

Comment: I have tried below code but still I am getting same result                                  
   for line in f:
        r = re.findall(r'[^\s"]+', line)
        #vin_quotes.append(line_quotes)
        vin_quotes.append(','.join(['"{0}"'.format(x) for x in r]))
        print(vin_quotes)
                
        
vin_df = pd.DataFrame(data = vin_quotes[1:])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following which simply matches any character that isn't `"` or a whitespace character `\s` one or more times, then joins the result together.

[See code in action here](https://tio.run/##hdBBa8IwGMbxez7FSy5pWSmtnTIPO3QqCa1CDxs7qANBxQxNy9seKrLP3rVparx5@/MLPLykuFanXEVNIy9FjhXggZAS3oGFPJ5n4w@glJpsa6P65pb5wCIbDdyl4dU4fZv3rPOBhWUx8OwrMCM6LU8tT@@cpGFiuEvDn4vvcNGzTs0jvsrS17hjk5ojHk@yQF9i8oGXlpdPWNgR0Y8wQrD9Rzz4R6n2u/PZQbb@2ZR0@8I8KF39Sj3q/@ZSOWtGb8EfZf4xx8uucmoX2oIapALcuqRAqSoH3ab5Bw)

```
import re

s = '1GADP5B """1GADP5B"""\n1GADP5G """1GADP5G"""\n1GAHP2G """1GAHP2G"""\n1GM5K8D """1GM5K8D"""\n1GM5K8H """1GM5K8H"""\n1GMCU0G """1GMCU0G"""\n1GMCU9G """1GMCU9G"""\n1GMJK1J """1GMJK1J"""\n1GTEW1E """1GTEW1E"""\n2GMPK4A """2GMPK4A"""\n3GA6P0H """3GA6P0H"""\n3GA6P0L """3GA6P0L"""\n3GA6P0L """3GA6P0L"""\n3GAHP0H """3GAHP0H"""'

r = re.findall(r'[^\s"]+', s)
r = ",".join(['"{0}"'.format(x) for x in r])
print(r)
```

Outputs the following:

```
"1GADP5B","1GADP5B","1GADP5G","1GADP5G","1GAHP2G","1GAHP2G","1GM5K8D","1GM5K8D","1GM5K8H","1GM5K8H","1GMCU0G","1GMCU0G","1GMCU9G","1GMCU9G","1GMJK1J","1GMJK1J","1GTEW1E","1GTEW1E","2GMPK4A","2GMPK4A","3GA6P0H","3GA6P0H","3GA6P0L","3GA6P0L","3GA6P0L","3GA6P0L","3GAHP0H","3GAHP0H"
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract `"word"`  from `""" word """`:

```py
import re
data = []

# extract all words between quotes
with open('C:/Users/name/Documents/TA/sample.tsv') as f:
    text = f.read()
    data = re.findall(r'"\w+"', text)

print(data)  # ['"1GADP5B"', '"1GADP5G"', '"1GAHP2G"',...'"3GA6P0L"', '"3GAHP0H"']

with open('C:/Users/name/Documents/TA/processed.tsv', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as w_f:
    w_f.write('\t'.join(data))  # or ','.join(data)
```

you want to write the result in `procossed.tsv` you have a list of words it's up to you to choose what you want as a seprator for `join`.